# how to add time in current time?

Tags: android, timestamp

When i run the program, the system current time is show in a textview.
Now i have a button, an edittext, and a textview.
I want When i put 40 on the edittext, i count this by the current hour second, and you display it by pushing the botton on a textview.
I just want to count the current hour second when i get it from edittext.
As you know when the current hour second is counted by a number, it will effect on the minute and hour too

help me please 
this code show current time :

```
    Thread myThread = null;
    Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
    myThread= new Thread(runnable);   
    myThread.start();
}
public void doWork() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{    
               txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbltime);
                    Date dt = new Date();
                    int hours = dt.getHours();
                    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                    String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                    txtCurrentTime.setText(curTime);
```

Comment: This is not very clear. What do you want to do and what is the problem?

Comment: yes, clear it what you want to do onclick.

Comment: what is the Unit of `40`? It is in second? You want to add the 40 seconds in currents time? If I understand you correct it is your solution `Date dt = new Date();
  long newTime =dt.getTime()+(40)/1000;
  
  Date newData=new Date(newTime);
  `

Comment: i wana add to current time with an edit text and a button and a text view . this code show's current time .

Comment: in edit text how the time will enter? In seconds, hours? in `newData` you will get the incremental time of `40 seconds`

Comment: i want every value that the user wants put on the edittext .

Comment: "edittext be as the seconds"?? If user enter 40 in `edittext`. and current time is `4h 20m 30s` then you want to show in text view `4h 21m 10s` ?

Comment: if user 40 in edittext then . Exactly i want to show in text view 4h 21m 10s .

Comment: Sorry! I am failed to understand what you want to ask and what is your problem?can you explain your problem with a example.

Comment: ok .now current time is 2h 30m 25s then  if a user enter 50 in edit text then be current time  2h 31m 15s

Comment: then see my answer..I hope it will solve your problem :) Btw It is same solutions. I post in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Time:

```
                txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcurrunt);
                Date dt = new Date();
                int hours = dt.getHours();
                int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                txtCurrentTime.setText(curTime);
```

User Input:

```
                userInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInputInSeconds);
                String userInput=userInput.getText().toString();
                long increment=Long.parseLong(userInput);
//New Time
              Date dt = new Date();
              long newTime =dt.getTime()+(increment)/1000;
              Date newData=new Date(newTime);
              int hours = newData.getHours();
              int minutes = newData.getMinutes();
              int seconds = newData.getSeconds();
              String newTimeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

              txtNewTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNew);
              txtNewTime.setText(newTimeString);
```

I hope it will help you...:)

Comment: thanks so much .     userInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInputInSeconds);
                String userInput=userInput.getText().toString();      i dont know what you mean ?

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem i don't think u had run the code there are bulk of errors i think u should have run it 1ce before posting answer

Comment: hi plz tell me if i want to decrement time on given time then what shud i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar. It would be easier for you to handle addition of seconds to current time.

```
int seconds=Integer.parseInt(mTextView.getText()); // get textview's value (in integer)

Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
String currentTimeString = String.format("%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS",cal);//24-hour format : HH:MM:SS

cal.add(Calendar.SECOND,seconds);
String newTimeString = String.format("%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS",cal);//24-hour format : HH:MM:SS
```

For more formats of date:visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html